# Sending email from localhost xampp with phpmailer error

Tags: php, email, xampp

I have installed xampp.

I am trying phpmailer to send email to `root@localhost.com`

I have created `root@localhost.com` account in Microsoft Outlook.

When trying to send email from Outlook to `root@localhost.com`, It is working.

But when I am trying to send email from PHP script on localserver, Email is not getting sent..Getting error.

I am trying following PHP code.

```
<?php
require("class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$body = "Testing";
$sub = "Testing Email";
$mail->IsHTML(true); 
//$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "localhost"; // SMTP server
$mail->From = "root@localhost.com"; // Your Full Email ID on your Domain
$mail->FromName = "Root User"; // Your name or Domain

$mail->AddAddress("root@localhost.com");

$mail->Subject = $sub;
$mail->Body = $body;
$mail->WordWrap = 50;
 if($mail->Send()){
    echo "Success";
}else{
    echo "Email Not Sent";
}
?>
```

I am getting the error

> Email Not Sent

I have googled for this issue. Setup Mercury, made changes accordingly in `php.ini` and `sendmail.ini` files too...

But No Success...

Answer (score 0):

Outlook is just an e-mail client, so creating an account for root@localhost.com in it doesn't mean your computer can now process send mail requests.

If you just need to test if your PHP is able to successfully post e-mails to a SMTP server, I suggest you use a tool like https://nilhcem.github.io/FakeSMTP/ (I do for development).

In production, you set your code to use a proper SMTP server. eg: [Send email using the GMail SMTP server from a PHP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-the-gmail-smtp-server-from-a-php-page)